# Append HTML element if it doesn't already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<p id="main_class">
    <span class="new_class"></span>
</p>
```

In following code I wanted to append `<span class="new_class"></span>` if it doesn't exists in the `main_class` and if it already exists then prevent appending the div.

I tried the following code

```
jQuery(".main_class").append('<span class="new_class">hello</span>');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors together:

```
jQuery("#main_class:not(:has(.new_class))").append('<span class="new_class">hello</span>');
```

Note that `main_class` is the `id`, so you select it with a hash (`#`)

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eZ7Gf/)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
if(jQuery(".main_class").find('.new_class').length==0){
    jQuery(".main_class").append('<span class="new_class">hello</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use ***.hasClass()*** in Jquery. It returns true  or false.Determine
>   whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

```
if(!jQuery("#main_class span").hasClass("new_class")){
     jQuery("#main_class").append('<span class="new_class">hello</span>');
}
```

or use ***.has()*** in jquery

```
if(!jQuery("#main_class span").has("new_class")){
     jQuery("#main_class").append('<span class="new_class">hello</span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `.main_class` class but we can only see an `id` and the class doesn't seem to exist.

try creating the class or using the `id` attribute :

```
$("#main_class")
```